# two fields with the same name create string instead of an array?

Tags: html, arrays

I've two fields with the same name name="s[]", but this creates an array, I don't need an array instead I'd like to construct a string.

I'm using these fields to submit search query to wordpress, if I will use an array I will have to mess with wordpress core, which I don't want. So my only option is to create 1 single string from two fields and submit it to query.

What do you think?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Why are there two fields?

Comment: Use JavaScript to combine the two results together into a single `hidden` field `OnSubmit`?

Comment: @jnylen To cut it short, it is for usability 1 field is for keyword the other field is for location, in reality I can do this in 1 field using AND logic so keyword1 AND location. Now it is hard to use 1 field for both keyw. and location so hence the need for two fields.

Comment: @mellamokb good idea. ty. +1. Could you rewrite it in answer? maybe with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two options:

- Submit the form to a different page, which redirects to the normal WordPress search page
- Catch the `onSubmit` event using JavaScript and rewrite / add to the form data

I would prefer option 1 because it will work for browsers that don't use JavaScript.  If you go with option 2, then you should not even show your two-field search interface to browsers that don't have JavaScript.

Comment: I went with the first option, captured get normally in php, made a string with two field content and submited it back. Works perfectly. ty.